# Eloquent Inner Join count

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I want to count rows in the table "links" where links.page_id = pages.id.

```
$link_item = Link::where('links.friendly_url', $id)
        ->join('pages','pages.id','=','links.page_id')
        ->select('pages.description as pdescription', 'pages.name', 'pages.photo as pphoto', 'pages.id as pid', 'links.*')
        ->get();

return view('site.link', compact('link_item'));
```

How I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `->count()` to the end of your query as you have it, or you can do

```
$link_item_count => $link_item->count();
```

Comment: I need to count only the table LINKS.

Comment: Is the relationship between page and link, one to many? One page has many links?